# Extracting data from a JSON response in Python and exclude also specific data

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I have following json_data in my Python shell:

```
[{u'alt_name': u'JON~1.EXT',
u'attributes': [u'DIRECTORY'],
u'create_time': 1538729344,
u'filename': u'Jon.Doe',
u'last_access_time': 1539071386,
u'last_write_time': 1539071386,
u'size': 0},

{u'attributes': [u'READONLY', u'DIRECTORY'],
u'create_time': 1536996830,
u'filename': u'Public',
u'last_access_time': 1538765229,
u'last_write_time': 1538765229,
u'size': 0},

{u'alt_name': u'ABC_IN~1',
u'attributes': [u'DIRECTORY'],
u'create_time': 1538729345,
u'filename': u'abc_inventory',
u'last_access_time': 1538729531,
u'last_write_time': 1538729531,
u'size': 0}]
```

I'm interested only in "filenames" and I would like to exclude "Public"

Goal:
Jon.Doe
abc_inventory

Thanks in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
json_data = [
     {u'alt_name': u'JON~1.EXT',
      u'attributes': [u'DIRECTORY'],
      u'create_time': 1538729344,
      u'filename': u'Jon.Doe',
      u'last_access_time': 1539071386,
      u'last_write_time': 1539071386,
      u'size': 0},

     {u'attributes': [u'READONLY', u'DIRECTORY'],
      u'create_time': 1536996830,
      u'filename': u'Public',
      u'last_access_time': 1538765229,
      u'last_write_time': 1538765229,
      u'size': 0},

     {u'alt_name': u'ABC_IN~1',
      u'attributes': [u'DIRECTORY'],
      u'create_time': 1538729345,
      u'filename': u'abc_inventory',
      u'last_access_time': 1538729531,
      u'last_write_time': 1538729531,
      u'size': 0}]


filenames = [i['filename'] for i in json_data]
```

the output will be:

```
['Jon.Doe', 'Public', 'abc_inventory']
```

if the logic is that to not get the `Public`:

```
filenames = [i['filename'] for i in json_data if i['filename'] !='Public']
```

the output will be:

```
['Jon.Doe', 'abc_inventory']
```

Comment: filenames = [i['filename'] for i in json_data if i['filename'] !='Public']